# How to run maven test with mysql running in docker

Tags: maven, docker

I have a maven java project. I need to run a mysql docker image in maven test stage to run tests and when its done i can remove mysql docker image.

Comment: Try referring to this link. https://hharnisc.github.io/2016/06/19/integration-testing-with-docker-compose.html
Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 8):

One example would be to use the Docker Maven Plugin (https://dmp.fabric8.io/). Here is an example pom that would start a MySQL container, do your integration tests using the Maven Failsafe Plugin, then stop the MySQL container. It also would pass the property `mysql.jdbc.url` to the tests so they have the right JDBC URL to the MySQL container running on the specific Docker host (which could be different depending how you are running Docker).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.20.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <alias>database</alias>
                            <name>mysql:5.7</name>
                            <run>
                                <wait>
                                    <log>mysqld: ready for connections</log>
                                    <time>20000</time>
                                </wait>
                                <env>
                                    <MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>abc123</MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>
                                    <MYSQL_DATABASE>testdb</MYSQL_DATABASE>
                                    <MYSQL_USER>mysql</MYSQL_USER>
                                    <MYSQL_PASSWORD>mysql</MYSQL_PASSWORD>
                                </env>
                                <ports>
                                    <port>3306:3306</port>
                                </ports>
                            </run>
                        </image>
                        <image>
                            <name>mvndemo</name>
                            <build>
                                <from>java:8-jre</from>
                                <assembly>
                                    <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                                </assembly>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>docker:start</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>docker:stop</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <mysql.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://${docker.host.address}/testdb</mysql.jdbc.url>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also opt for [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) you will need to change the driver to a specific JDBC driver from testcontainer that will do the spinning up and spinning down of your required service. They also support other databases and versions. It is quite easy to do. You also get the option to startup and stop the container yourself from within a junit test if you need advanced stuff like initialization scripts.